# Bulk video downloader especially for DailyMotion

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, download-manager

I want to download hundreds of video files from a user account on [DailyMotion.com](http://www.dailymotion.com). The videos are located under the URL as in the following example:

http://www.dailymotion.com/mplay

Is there a *free* program that can mass download all videos in that gallery? I tried [DailyMotion Video Downloader](http://www.downloadmost.com/freeware/software/?Dailymotion%20Video%20Downloader-9278.html) but it can only download if I give each video link one by one.

**Important note:** I just want to enter any link (for example, `www.dailymotion.com/mplay`) into the program and then it should handle *everything* (grab all sublinks; start and finish download automatically).

Answer (score 3):

Try [JDownloader CLI](http://jdownloader.org/knowledge/wiki/terminal/index). They say they have [Dailymotion-Support](http://jdownloader.org/hoster/dailymotion.com).

EDIT: In GUI version, you're even able to add all links at once.

EDIT: Didn't get you haven't got a list of all movies. Using bash and lynx (text based web browser), it is quiet easy to get all video URLs (or exactly, the first 100 pages * 20 videos, dailymotion does not print more, I'm also getting the most viewed and best rated lists to maximize cover):

```
{ for i in {1..100}; do lynx -dump -nonumbers -listonly http://www.dailymotion.com/user/mplay/$i http://www.dailymotion.com/visited/user/mplay/$i http://www.dailymotion.com/rated/user/mplay/$i; echo $i 1>&2; done } |grep http://www.dailymotion.com/video/ |sort |uniq >movies.txt
```

Don't try to change the 100, there aren't any more than that. If you find a way to list the missing videos, tell me!

Just adjust the username ("mplay") if neccessary and paste this line into bash. Wait for some time until finished and you will get your list printed which you can reuse in jdownloader.

In case you're not using linux (or OS X and installed lynx) I [dumped the list for you](https://gist.github.com/7030785dab285c78118f). Have fun with it! But I'm not quit sure why I found more distinct videos than dailymotion says there are.

Comment: OK but I need **Bulk** download support. It cannot do it (at least the free version, from what I know).

Comment: There is no "un-free" version. JDownloader runs as a background service, then you can add all your links using `JDownloader -add <link>` which will be queued and downloaded without further interaction. In GUI version, you can even add all links from clipboard at once.

Comment: So you say, when I enter `http://www.dailymotion.com/mplay` in JDownloader, it will start the download process? Because I don't want to enter 4500 links one by one.

Comment: Well you need to get the links somehow. Will be updating my post with some lines of bash script in a few minutes.

Comment: there you are, have fun with it.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for your efforts. I forgot to tell I'm using Windows 7.